# Custom stylesheets in Django (1.3) admin

Tags: css, django, django-admin

I've got several custom stylesheets that override default admin styles. They live in `myproject/static/admin/css-extended`. I'm overriding several of Django's default admin templates with templates that live in 'myproject/templates/admin'.

In the templates my stylesheet references are: `{{ STATIC_URL }}/admin/css-extended/[stylesheet].css`.

However, I can't get the custom stylesheets to pull through.

I've got the following url-related settings in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

I've got the following template context processors listed:

```
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.core.context_processors.static',
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I suspect the issue has something to do with the fact that my `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is the same as the first part of the css-extended url (`'/static/admin'`). I guess Django is trying to find a directory called 'css-extended' in the core admin rather than in the project itself. But how do I get round this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you having this problem on your local dev environment (with runserver)? If so, do you have the following in your urls.py?

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Read the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) for more.

Comment: Yes, I'm using runserver. According to the docs you referred to, you only need to add those extra lines if you're serving up static files using something other than the built in dev server though.

Comment: Good point. Have you looked at the page source to see how {{ STATIC_URL }} is being rendered in the template?

Comment: Does 127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css-extended/foo.css return the file?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I now think I know what's going on here.  Hopefully this will clarify:

**STATIC_ROOT** is only used by the "collectstatic" management command, to figure out where to dump the static files it collects.

**STATIC_URL** is used by the dev server to define the URL at which the static files will be served.

**STATICFILES_DIRS**, which you haven't set, is used by both the dev server and the "collectstatic" management command to identify the locations of the static files to serve.   In the case of the dev server, the files are served directly in place.  In the case of the management command, the files are gathered and copied into STATIC_ROOT.

[Note: there's a convention here -- if you have /static subdirectories in your apps (not your project), they'll be picked up along with anything explicitly defined in STATICFILES_DIRS.]

You just need to add the following to settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = {
        '/absolute/path/to/myproject/static/',
}
```

Comment: I already tried that. It throws the following error: 'ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting'.

Comment: Ah, solved it! I just changed the value of STATIC_ROOT to `absolute/path/to/myproject/staticfiles` instead of `absolute/path/to/myproject/static` to avoid that error. Presumably the directory name of STATIC_ROOT can be anything you like... (I haven't tested it on a production server yet)?

Comment: If i understood it right (just one week using django yet, so Im sorry if I'm mistaken), the STATIC_ROOT path is just an absolute path to where the static files will go when you run the command from manage.py, not the static files directory itself. Te comment above the STATIC_ROOT configuration line does say so, that you shouldn't even put any files on that directory on your own, because it is reserved for the files collected by the "collectstatic" management function